# Error message while installing any software?

Tags: software-center, dependencies, error-handling

Whenever I am installing VLC in Ubuntu software center, I am getting following Error, How to solve this problem?

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

libavcodec53:i386: Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8.1) but it is not installed
               Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (< 4:0.8.1.99) but it is not installed
               Depends: libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13) but it is not installed
               Depends: libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
               Depends: libva1 (> 1.0.15~) but it is not installed
               Depends: libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0) but it is not installed
libavformat53:i386: Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libavcodec-extra-53 (< 4:0.8.1.99) but it is not installed
                Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (< 4:0.8.1.99) but it is not installed
libpostproc52:i386: Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8.1) but it is not installed
                Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (< 4:0.8.1.99) but it is not installed
libswscale2:i386: Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8.1) but it is not installed
              Depends: libavutil-extra-51 (< 4:0.8.1.99) but it is not installed
```

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` and `sudo apt-get -f install`.

Answer (score 0):

Software center is telling you that you must also install:

```
libavcodec-extra-53 (>= 4:0.8.1)
libavcodec-extra-53 (< 4:0.8.1.99)
libavutil-extra-51 (>= 4:0.8.1)
libavutil-extra-51 (< 4:0.8.1.99)
libgsm1 (>= 1.0.13)
libschroedinger-1.0-0 (>= 1.0.0)
libva1 (> 1.0.15~)
libvpx1 (>= 1.0.0)
```

The numbers in the parentheses specify constraints on the versions of the additional packages desired.

Comment: This is not really helpful for newbies yet. Please explain detailed steps.